# Java Android Pass Function as an argument to runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-runonuithread

I'm not a Java expert and I would like to understand how to pass a function that must be performed with runOnUiThread

Something similar to this

```
public void runOnActivity(FUNCTION) {
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FUNCTION();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

and then

```
public void reload(){
    runOnActivity(mContext.reload);
}
```

Or even better, since they should always be called as mContext methods:

```
public void runOnActivity(METHOD_NAME) {
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mContext.METHOD_NAME();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

and then

```
public void reload(){
    runOnActivity("reload");
}
```

All functions always return VOID
I hope I explained myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can include your function in `Runnable` block like this

```
Runnable myFunction = () -> System.out.println("some function");

void runOnMain(Runnable runnable) {
  mActivity. runOnUiThread {
    runnable.run();
  }
}
```

Finally, call your method:

```
runOnMain(myFunction);
```

I hope, you will switch to Kotlin soon and perform such actions much easier :)